# Move numbers to the bottom

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, pagestyle

I am new in LaTeX. I started a project with an overleaf template. Now I am trying to move the numbers of the page to the bottom to avoid them to overlap with the headings, to do that I has been playing with these lines with no success:

```
\pagestyle{fancyplain}%\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}
\textheight22.5cm \topmargin0cm \textwidth16.5cm
\oddsidemargin0.5cm \evensidemargin-0.5cm%
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\; #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\; #1}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\rightmark}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\thepage}}
\fancyfoot{}
\thispagestyle{plain}%
```

Do you know how I could modify this to move the numbers of the pages to the bottom?

Comment: Welcome to the newcomer to the site TeX.SE.

Comment: To get the page number into the foot use for example `\cfoot{\thepage}` ... Can you please complete your code snippet to be compilable?

Answer (score 1):

At the end I did this:

```
\pagestyle{fancyplain}%\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}
\textheight22.5cm \topmargin0cm \textwidth16.5cm
\oddsidemargin0.5cm \evensidemargin-0.5cm%
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\; #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\; #1}}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove the header rule
\rfoot{\thepage}
%\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\rightmark}}
%\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\thepage}}
%\fancyfoot{}
\thispagestyle{plain}%
```

Probably wasn't and elegant solution. I removed the headings and moved the page number to the bottom.